# if statement's condition element > number gives strange results

Tags: javascript

The title is very general but I think I'm lacking the words to explain this properly.

So I'm fetching some data from an external API and I want to filter some of the results. I'm using a `forEach` to loop through the response and after that an if statement to exclude some of them based on some criteria.

So in this case I'm fetching some movie data and I want to exclude movies that return without img URL. This part works fine. Next I want to exclude movies that have a low popularity level. The popularity level on the JSON object is set with a number in the form of i.e. 4.45644.

```
const findMovies = response.results;
  findMovies.forEach( movie => {
    if (movie.poster_path != null && movie.popularity > 8) {
       // print to DOM
    } else {
      //dont print nothing
    }
```

The problem is that with the above code I"m filtering out all movies that have a popularity smaller OR bigger than 8. I'm sure I'm missing something really stupid but I've spent a couple of hours stuck so far.

Let me know if you need any other code snippets that might be helpful.

This is basically what the API response logs on the console

```
results: Array(20)
  0:
    adult:false
    poster_path: "/tjQHn6xW5BiB1RJ3OZIPDzIOSkF.jpg"
    popularity: 30.400022
    ....
```

Comment: if you want to exclude movies with no image url and popularity less than 8 then in your if condition you should use OR condition if (movie.poster_path != null || movie.popularity > 8)

Comment: What exactly you need as expected output? if path is not null and popularity is bigger than 8, then print? is that?

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty Both ways will work since all the high rated movies come with img url anyway. But you are right. What you pointed out is the correct way for what I want to do. Unfortunately I still get the same results

Comment: @CalvinNunes exactly and it works partly so far. It doesn't print if there is no url path but excludes results with popularity under AND over 8. Which is something i don't want

Comment: Maybe popularity does not exist in the objects? Or `poster_path` should be `backdrop_path`

Comment: Can you post a working code example please? Because the behavior of your code seems mysterious and it's quite hard to guess the reason.

Comment: Maybe it's the `>` symbol and you need `>=` for greater than or equal to. Is your problem you are getting 9+ not 8+ ?

Comment: @JonasW. Sorry `backdrop_path` was a typo. I corrected it to `poster_path` . And popularity exists on all object. I console log for reference all the time

Comment: @agm1984 Nope.Doesn't work either. I'm only getting movies with popularity of 8.000001 to 8.999999 . I am not getting anything above or bellow. I need everything from 8 and above to pass through the statement.

Comment: In general, I'd put parenthesis around the various logical elements, it never hurts, and it may help, depending on order-of-operations and the language itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code we can examine. I want to forget about your existing code and get to the meat of the problem which is to pull a list of movies and analyze them and sort them in some custom way.

I chose to use `Array.reduce()` because it allows us to step over each movie that comes from your DB and analyze it for whatever we feel like, then it creates an output Object that filters matching results and maintains a list of rejected movies.

I did this because I want you to know how `reduce` works (because it's awesome)

```
// Simulate the Movie DB
const movies = [
  { title: 'Sammy goes to the store', poster_path: 'http://www.com/photo.jpg', popularity: 2, url: 'http://www.com' },
  { title: 'Sammy doesnt go to the store', poster_path: 'http://www.com/photo.jpg', popularity: 4, url: '' },
  { title: 'Willy goes to Whalemart', poster_path: 'http://www.com/photo.jpg', popularity: 6, url: 'http://www.com' },
  { title: 'Jimmy only had one job', poster_path: 'http://www.com/photo.jpg', popularity: 8, url: '' },
  { title: 'Jimmy no longer has one job', poster_path: 'http://www.com/photo.jpg', popularity: 10, url: 'http://www.com' },
  { title: 'Fred goes to the farm', poster_path: undefined, popularity: 12, url: 'http://www.com' },
  { title: 'Fred doesnt go to the farm', poster_path: 'http://www.com/photo.jpg', popularity: 14, url: '' },
  { title: 'Helga goes to the hackathon', poster_path: 'http://www.com/photo.jpg', popularity: 16, url: 'http://www.com' },
  { title: 'Bhima only had one job', poster_path: 'http://www.com/photo.jpg', popularity: 18, url: '' },
  { title: 'Bhima no longer has one job', poster_path: null, popularity: 20, url: 'http://www.com' },
]

// Simulate the network request to get the movies
const response = { results: movies }

// Start with your existing code
const findMovies = response.results

// Rather than forEach, we will use Array.map() or Array.reduce()
// and set the filtered results into a new Array,
// because it provides you more utility overall
const filteredMovies = findMovies.reduce((acc, movie) => {
  if (movie.poster_path == null) {
    // console.log('REJECTING:', movie, 'REASON: no photo')
    movie.rejectReason = 'no photo'
    acc.rejects.push(movie)
    return acc
  }
  if (movie.popularity < 8) {
    // console.log('REJECTING:', movie, 'REASON: bad rating')
    movie.rejectReason = 'bad rating'
    acc.rejects.push(movie)
    return acc
  }
  acc.matches.push(movie)
  return acc
}, { matches: [], rejects: [] })

console.log('MATCHES', filteredMovies.matches)

console.log('\nREJECTS', filteredMovies.rejects)
```

First, `Array.map()` or `Array.reduce()` are very similar to `Array.forEach()`. If you already know this, amazing -- I love you. All three of them step over an iterable and do something with each item. The difference is map produces a new Array and reduce can produce **any** data structure. This makes the process **immutable** and good practice. You will have to research immutability on your own. If you do, pay attention to how JavaScript maintains live references to non-primitives. This can create nightmares when "shared mutable state" is involved.

Second, `Array.reduce()` is a little extra than map because it is an accumulator. If you aren't familiar, I extremely recommend learning all about reduce. Long story short, in my example, we are accumulating an Object that has two keys: `matches` and `rejects`. We are stepping over each item in the movies Array and analyzing it with your original logic, but I flipped it around to the inverse of what you had. It goes like this:

1) Examine each movie

2) If `movie.poster_path == null`: movie is a reject, push it into the reject array we are accumulating. Using `==` will catch all falsy values, such as `''`, `0`, `undefined`, and `null`.

3) If `movie.popularity < 8`: movie is a reject, push it into the reject Array we are accumulating.

4) Before we move to the next movie in the list, we add a `rejectReason` property into the movie result (just in case we want to examine that later or display it in an error message).

5) Notice how the reduce function is a list of if statements that cause a rejection, and the final step says: "If the movie wasn't rejected yet, add it to the `matches` Array we are accumulating.

**Bonus note**: `acc` stands for accumulator. If you look close, we are accumulating something while the reduce function is looping over each item. When it says `return acc`. It means, return the accumulator back so the next item can use it too.

Since you spent a long time on this issue, I wanted to help you understand how to think about doing this kind of "transformation from a list to a filtered set". I use and advocate functional programming techniques. map, filter, and reduce are central to this way of thinking, and so are immutable data structures and generally one way data flow. Note these keywords I am dropping and always pay attention when people talk about them. These things will become more and more attractive to you as you do more crazy asynchronous event handling in complex apps.

Comment: Wow! This not only worked but it was also a great lesson on .reduce(). BTW any idea about why my code didn't work properly? Anyway Thanks a bunch! this was really helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. Reduce is great. It's like a swiss army knife any time you need to transform a list into literally anything. I wasn't able to see why your code wasn't working. I tested the logic and your `if statement` worked for me the way I expected it to.

Comment: My only note about that is that you used `!=` which works, but it is a bit of a strong and sloppy comparison. Likewise with `!==`, but the falsy check you were doing is among the most valid of usages for those, so don;t feel bad. Just be aware of `type coercion` and try to always use `!==` unless you decide not to.

Comment: If you want to find the problem, try to keep stripping the code down as much as possible until its just your original `forEach` loop and doing some `console.log()`s. See if you can visually inspect them and find out why it wasn't working. I would actually consider that exercise worth your time because you will probably learn some small detail. In my experience, fiddling with little nuances in JavaScript is always worth it. Many small details add up over time.

Comment: Another thing that is different about my example vs. your original code is that mine although it looks kind of complex is actually more simple because the code is parsed synchronously and it is always only doing 1 thing at a time. I was just reading my answer again and I noted that. Your original code was checking two conditions at the same time, so that alone can increase a chance of weird edge cases that are at least harder for a human to observe quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  const findMovies = response.results;
    findMovies.forEach( movie => {
      if (movie.poster_path != null && (8-movie.popularity> 0d)){
         // print to DOM
      } else {
         //dont print anything
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
const result = findMovies.filter(movies => movies.popularity > 8);
console.log(result);
```

This will filter the array with the end result of returning only movies with a popularity of greater than 8. You can then use .forEach() at the end of that also to iterate through that result if you are only looking for certain values from the keys etc